# Extending Remote vs UnicastRemoteObject

Tags: java, rmi

What is the difference between extending Remote vs. extending UnicastRemoteObject? When do I want one or the other?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a false opposition. They are not in competition: you don't have to choose between them:

1. Your remote interface must extend `Remote.`
2. Your remote object must implement your remote interface. It can either extend `UnicastRemoteObject` or be exported manually by calling `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject().`